# how to create a mutator methods with boolean

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I was asked to create a class that implement a queue of jobs using Array List.
We can add jobs and runtime to the queue. A job runs from the front of the queue in the JobInQueue list, myPendingTime gets subtracted and the completed job goes to the Finishedjobs list.

It looks like we have to use boolean mutator method for this but I am not sure how to create this method.
could anyone tell me how to do this.

```
/**
  * runs the first job on the queue if there is enough time on the clock.
  */
public boolean runJob()
{
    boolean jobDone = runJob(); 
     if(myJobInQueue.isEmpty() && myDuration > myPendingTime){
       myDuration-= myPendingTime;
       myJobInQueue.remove(0);
       myFinishedJobs.add(myJobInQueue.get(0));
       System.out.println("The job runing is : "+ myJobInQueue.get(0));
       jobDone=true;
     }
    return jobDone ; 
}
```

Comment: You first line of method will create infinite Recursion result in `Maximum Recursion Depth`..

Comment: You are removing the job from the queue before putting in the finished queue. It should be opposite i.e. `myJobInQueue.remove(0);` should be after `myFinishedJobs.add(myJobInQueue.get(0));`.

Comment: Make the method return as `void`, change`boolean jobDone = false;` from the top and put this `if(!jobDone){ runJob(); }` in the bottom. Remove the `return jobDone` line.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer, I have replaced the myJobInQueue...now how to I return the boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your inputs, please find the updated program below:

```
  public void runJob(){
    boolean jobDone = false; 
    if(!myJobInQueue.isEmpty() && myDuration > myPendingTime){
         myDuration-= myPendingTime;
         myFinishedJobs.add(myJobInQueue.get(0));
         myJobInQueue.remove(0);
         System.out.println("The job runing is : "+ myJobInQueue.get(0));
        jobDone=true;
    }
    if(!jobDone ){
         runJob();
    } 
  }
```

Also I believe you want to check, `myJobInQueue` is not empty i.e. `if(!myJobInQueue.isEmpty() && myDuration > myPendingTime)`.